# Handling Excel File with Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm trying to read an excel file with `Pandas`.

1. I'm trying to only read column 2 through column 4.
2. I'm trying to skip reading the first 9 rows.
3. Even with, `skiprows=8, parse_col=["B:D"],`my data stored in `df` looks the same as the incoming excel file, and it doesn't exclude the first 9 rows or exclude the desired columns.

What is wrong with my syntax and why isn't the database structure stored in `df` my inputted excel file minus 9 rows and a few columns?

My incoming data below:

```
Null,Null,Null,Null,Null,Null,Null,Null,Null    
Null,Null,Null,Null,Null,Null,Null,Null,Null    
Null,Null,Null,Null,Null,Null,Null,Null,Null    
Null,Null,Null,Null,Null,Null,Null,Null,Null                
Null,Null,Null,Null,Null,Null,Null,Null,Null                                
Null,Null,Null,Null,Null,Null,Null,Null,Null                    
Null,Null,Null,Null,Null,Null,Null,Null,Null                                
Null,Null,Null,Null,String1,String2,Null,Null,Null  
Null,Phase to Phase Voltage,A - B,210.0,C - A,211.0,B - C,212.0 
Null,Circuit/Breaker,Number,Internal Meter Amps,External Meter Amps,Measured Difference,% Difference,Location Identifier,Total Location Amperage,Comments
Null,Main Phase A,94.1,96.,2.8,3%,Null,Null,Null            
Null,Main Phase B,90.1,92.6,2.5,3%,Null,Null,Null           
Null,Main Phase C,91.9,92.1,0.2,0%,Null,Null,Null       
Null,Neutral,0.0,0.4,0.4,100%,Null,Null,Null            
Null,Ground 0.0,0.1,0.1,100%,Null,Null,Null         
Null,1,10.6,10.2,-0.4,-4%,Null,Null,Null            
Null,2,10.6,10.3,-0.3,-3%,Null,Null,Null                
....
```

My code is below:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('filelocation.xlsx',  sheetname=['pnl1 Data ','pnl2 Data','pnl3 Data','pnl4 Data'], skiprows=8, parse_col=["B:D"], keep_default_na='FALSE', na_values=['NULL'])
```

Comment: Never heard about this problem. Have you tried to read only one sheet (`sheet name`) instead of several ? If you try to read several sheets `read_excel` returns a Dict of `DataFrames`, with keys representing sheets. I think that reproducing the problem with only one sheet could permit to locate the problem.

Comment: I get the same issues when trying to parse just one sheet. My new line looks like this: `df = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/Jerry/Documents/panoptics/panopticsMeeting2.28.16/FDC 1301 Data Collection (upTo48BreakerDevice) - original.xlsx',  sheetname=['pnl1 Data '], skiprows=8, parse_col=["B:D"], keep_default_na='FALSE', na_values=['NULL'])`

Answer (score 1):

You've misspelled the `parse_cols` parameter name, use `parse_cols` instead of `parse_col`. Beside that you should either specify a string like `"B:D"` (or `"B,C,D"`) or a list like `['B','C','D']`

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('filelocation.xlsx',
        sheetname=['pnl1 Data ','pnl2 Data','pnl3 Data','pnl4 Data'],
        skiprows=8, parse_cols="B:D", keep_default_na='FALSE', na_values=['NULL'])
```

PS Also check this sheet_name: `'pnl1 Data '` for the trailing space

Comment: The sheet name actually has a trailing space in it, so that was put in on purpose. Also, When I change `parse_col` to `parse_cols`, I got the following error: `
  File "C:\Users\Jerry\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1817, in _next_line
    raise StopIteration

StopIteration`

Comment: I'm sorry. Nvm. When I inserted your code, it worked. Some syntax in my code must be wrong.